# If there's acid rain, is there such thing as acid snow?

Tags: weather

If so, would the acid snow just be as damaging?

Answer (score 1):

As [explained by user voltaic at reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/askscience/comments/1wkrty/if_theres_acid_rain_is_there_such_thing_as_acid/cf2zim4):

> Yes, there is, and it can be more of a problem than acid rain.
>
> For one, when snow is falling it spends more time travelling through
>   the atmosphere before hitting the ground than rain. As a result of
>   this, it has more time to collect pollutants, and can become more
>   acidic than typical acid rain for the same region. There's additional
>   factors that complicate this however, such as the solubility of the
>   pollutant, the temperature and the water content of the snow, etc.
>   (e.g. warmer snow which is more "wet" is going to dissolve more than
>   cooler, drier snow.)
>
> Once the snow hits the ground, the dissolved pollutants are going to
>   stay in solution, or trapped within the crystalline structure of the
>   snow until it melts. Because of this, snow can pile up and then thaw,
>   releasing all the pollutants and acidic water in a relatively short
>   amount of time. This can have fairly substantial effects on the
>   environment.
>
> You can read a bit more about this here:
>
> - http://www.elmhurst.edu/~chm/vchembook/191acidsnow.html
> - http://dwb4.unl.edu/Chem/CHEM869V/CHEM869VLinks/www.qesn.meq.gouv.qc.ca/cc/acidrain/info6.htm

Acid snow is also mentioned in passing on the [acid rain wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acid_rain).

The "fairly substantial effects on the environment", as described by the links above, largely involve a large release of acid during the spring thaw, which effectively releases all of the acid built up over the winter in a relatively short period. This can result in lowered pH in waterways, which can affect fish, amphibians and crustaceans.